# How to make a ripple effect over irregular shaped image?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

In my project I have irregular shaped image that I want to use as a button. On tap there is a ripple effect but I have no idea how to clip it to its bounds (and how to set them). I've seen ClipRect, ClipRRect etc. widgets, but none of them match the image shape.

Comment: use `ClipPath` then - a tip: build a local documentation based on your installed flutter sources - which gives you a handy "Search API docs" text field on the top right of the page

Comment: @pskink I've considered this solution, but this shape is very difficult to recreate in the code. Is there any way to generate Path for non transparent part of the image?

Comment: i dont think so - in that case you would need to write clipping on your own custom widget

Comment: If you use the image on a plain background, and you don't use any shadow, you could use a Stack as workaround. You can reverse the shape of your image and give it the same color as the background. You apply this on top of your image. It will look like the image got clipped.